# Submiting javascript code from HTML form and then run the code

Tags: javascript, html

I want the user to type in javascript code in the textarea of a HTML form, then test the code, and be able to see the results. Perhaps the results can go in an iframe on the same page.

I realize this can be potentially dangerous. What things do I need to be careful about?

This might be something like what codeacademy does.